# Why does Keras' fit_generator sometimes not call on_epoch_end() on validation data generator?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tf.keras

I've noticed that Keras will sometimes fail to call the `on_epoch_end()` method of my `keras.utils.Sequence` **validation data** generator, especially when each step of model evaluation is fast (e.g. when batch size is small).

For example here is a minimal working example to demonstrate Keras' difference in behavior on a batch size of 1 and a batch size of 64:

```
    import numpy as np
    from tensorflow.keras import layers, models
    from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence

    FEATURE_SIZE = 512 ** 2


    class DataGenerator(Sequence):

        def __init__(self, batch_size, log=False):
            self.batch_size = batch_size
            self.log = log

        def __len__(self):
            return 1

        def __getitem__(self, i):
            return np.ones((self.batch_size, FEATURE_SIZE)), np.ones((self.batch_size, 1))  # Some dummy data

        def on_epoch_end(self):
            if self.log:
                print('on_epoch_end() called')


    def train(batch_size):
        print('Training with batch_size =', batch_size)
        training_generator = DataGenerator(batch_size)
        test_generator = DataGenerator(batch_size, log=True)

        model = models.Sequential()
        model.add(layers.Dense(4, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=[FEATURE_SIZE]))
        model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=[FEATURE_SIZE]))
        model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

        model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator, validation_data=test_generator, epochs=5, verbose=0)


    train(batch_size=1)
    train(batch_size=64)
```

I get the output:

```
    Training with batch_size = 1
    on_epoch_end() called

    Training with batch_size = 64
    on_epoch_end() called
    on_epoch_end() called
    on_epoch_end() called
    on_epoch_end() called
    on_epoch_end() called
```

It is clear from the output that `on_epoch_end()` is being called a different amount of times depending on the batch size.

This is highly problematic as my data generator expects `on_epoch_end()` to be reliably called once after every epoch.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

---

I'm using Keras version:

```
    tensorflow.keras.__version__
    Out[143]: '2.1.6-tf'
```

Comment: Hi  @mchen, Tried executing your code on google colab, and its working fine. tf version 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I have added below statements to your code and executed, `on_epoch_end` was called only once for `batch_size=64` and not called even once for `batch_size=1`. Also, I am using same version of `tensorflow.keras.__version__`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tensorflow.keras.__version__)
```

**Code -**

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
print(tensorflow.keras.__version__)
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence

FEATURE_SIZE = 512 ** 2


class DataGenerator(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, batch_size, log=False):
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.log = log

    def __len__(self):
        return 1

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return np.ones((self.batch_size, FEATURE_SIZE)), np.ones((self.batch_size, 1))  # Some dummy data

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        if self.log:
            print('on_epoch_end() called')


def train(batch_size):
    print('Training with batch_size =', batch_size)
    training_generator = DataGenerator(batch_size)
    test_generator = DataGenerator(batch_size, log=True)

    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(4, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=[FEATURE_SIZE]))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=[FEATURE_SIZE]))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator, validation_data=test_generator, epochs=5, verbose=0)

train(batch_size=1)
train(batch_size=64)
```

**Output -**

```
2.1.6-tf
Training with batch_size = 1
Training with batch_size = 64
on_epoch_end() called
```

Have modified your code a little to use `callbacks` as below and it worked fine as expected.

**Fixed code -**

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
print(tensorflow.keras.__version__)
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence

FEATURE_SIZE = 512 ** 2

# Define the Required Callback Function
class printepoch(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
      print("on_epoch_end() called")

printepochs = printepoch() 

class DataGenerator(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, batch_size, log=False):
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.log = log

    def __len__(self):
        return 1

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return np.ones((self.batch_size, FEATURE_SIZE)), np.ones((self.batch_size, 1))  # Some dummy data

    # def on_epoch_end(self):
    #     if self.log:
    #         print('on_epoch_end() called')


def train(batch_size):
    print('Training with batch_size =', batch_size)
    training_generator = DataGenerator(batch_size)
    test_generator = DataGenerator(batch_size)

    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(4, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=[FEATURE_SIZE]))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=[FEATURE_SIZE]))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator, validation_data=test_generator, epochs=5, verbose=0, callbacks=[printepochs])


train(batch_size=1)
train(batch_size=64)
```

**Output -**

```
2.1.6-tf
Training with batch_size = 1
on_epoch_end() called
on_epoch_end() called
on_epoch_end() called
on_epoch_end() called
on_epoch_end() called
Training with batch_size = 64
on_epoch_end() called
on_epoch_end() called
on_epoch_end() called
on_epoch_end() called
on_epoch_end() called
```

But when I ran your code in `2.3.0-tf` version, it worked perfectly fine. Probably its fixed in the later versions.

Hope this answers your question.